# Cordova-2.1.0 capture and upload photo to server

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I'm new here and have a problem in last week:

I made an app in phonegap(cordova2.1.0) and this is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var deviceReady = false;

/**
 * Take picture with camera
 */
function takePicture() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function(uri) {
            var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
            img.style.visibility = "visible";
            img.style.display = "block";
            img.src = uri;
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";
        },
        function(e) {
            console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
        },
        { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
};

/**
 * Select picture from library
 */
function selectPicture() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        function(uri) {
            var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
            img.style.visibility = "visible";
            img.style.display = "block";
            img.src = uri;
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";
        },
        function(e) {
            console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
        },
        { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY});
};

/**
 * Upload current picture
 */
function uploadPicture() {

    // Get URI of picture to upload
    var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
    var imageURI = img.src;
    if (!imageURI || (img.style.display == "none")) {
        document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Take picture or select picture from library first.";
        return;
    }

    // Verify server has been entered
    server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;
    if (server) {

        // Specify transfer options
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        // Transfer picture to server
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload successful: "+r.bytesSent+" bytes uploaded.";              
        }, function(error) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = "+error.code;               
        }, options);
    }
}

/**
 * View pictures uploaded to the server
 */
function viewUploadedPictures() {

    // Get server URL
    server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;
    if (server) {

        // Get HTML that lists all pictures on server using XHR 
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Callback function when XMLHttpRequest is ready
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4){

                // HTML is returned, which has pictures to display
                if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                    document.getElementById('server_images').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }

                // If error
                else {
                    document.getElementById('server_images').innerHTML = "Error retrieving pictures from server.";
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", server , true);
        xmlhttp.send();         
    }   
}

/**
 * Function called when page has finished loading.
 */
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {deviceReady = true;}, false);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (!deviceReady) {
            alert("Error: PhoneGap did not initialize.  Demo will not run correctly.");
        }
    },2000);
}
```

HTML code:

**Image:**

```
    <input type="button" onclick="takePicture();" value="Take Picture" /><br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="selectPicture();" value="Select Picture from Library" /><br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="uploadPicture();" value="Upload Picture" />
</div>
<br/>
```

well: part of this code is not mine.

QUESTION

there is no error alert

the alert says everything was done. image uploaded and the bytes

in my msql the image has no the extension(.jpg) only the name

and in the images folder theres nothing uploaded

i whitelisted everything,

can anibody help me?
I don't know wat else to do..

thanks in advance

by the way in eclipse log everithing shows ok too,
in android 2.3 actual phone the same thing, but the image is not there..